# How to remove circle cursor in brush tool in Adobe illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

For a long period I was using Illustrator CS6 and it's UI was quite friendly and responsive.
Now I switched to Illustrator CC and a bit frustrated by its innovations.

For example I can't find a way how to remove that annoying small circle on the end of brush tool. The brush tool in Illustrator CS6 didn't have that circle.
What a genius developer had invented this piece of waste?...

Comment: I think that circle is quite helpful as it shows the size and shape of the brush tip. But it would be good if you could change cursor settings as in photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it can't be removed unless you choose a brush that doesn't have an elliptical brush tip.

[image]

Comment: the point is that I need to remove that circle from calligraphic brush.